# Robot.createScreenCapture bound to monitor refresh rate on Windows 10

Tags: java, swing

Ran into a very strange issue. I am writing an application that captures 100 images per second on my main monitor. This is done using `Robot.createScreenCapture(Rectangle)`. I also have a Swing window open on my left monitor, which is only 60hz, that just shows debug information which is re-drawn at 60fps. Main monitor is 144hz.

Here's where the weirdness comes into play. If I move that Swing window to my main window, I am able to capture 100 images per second, as the application is intended for. However, if I move that Swing window to my LEFT 60hz monitor, the `Robot.createScreenCapture(Rectangle)` that is still capturing my MAIN 144hz monitor, is suddenly slowed down to only capture 60 images per second.

If I don't update the Swing window, and put it on my left monitor, the capture speed is unaffected. However, if the Swing window is redrawn - like if there's an update to it, then it will delay the next frame.

I am using multiple threads, so it's not some thread shallow thread locking issue on my application.

I was expecting my application to be able to capture 100 images per second. Instead, moving my Swing window on my slower 60hz monitor doubles the time it takes to capture an image.

Comment: You are fixated on the frequency. What really affects the time to capture the screen is the screen resolution. Higher resolution - more pixels.

Comment: @Just another Java programmer
No you did not read my post, or I failed to properly explain the issue. It is able to achieve 100 fps effortlessly. If I move the swing window on my 60hz monitor, it suddenly gets capped at that monitors refresh rate.